# How to disable some function in javascript when mobile device is use to open my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

How I can disable some of my js script function when mobile device is used to open my webpage?
I can make it if it's on css only, but some button need to have function on js.
this is my internal js code

```
var menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu")
var sideNav = document.getElementById("header")
var xBtn = document.getElementById("xBtn")
var slidePage = document.getElementById("main-page")

sideNav.style.right = "-250px";

menuBtn.onclick = function(){
    if(sideNav.style.right == "-250px"){
        sideNav.style.right = "0";
        menuBtn.style.display = "none";
        slidePage.style.left = "-9%";
    }
    else{
        sideNav.style.right = "-250px";
        menuBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
}

xBtn.onclick = function(){
        sideNav.style.right = "-250px";
        slidePage.style.left = "0";
        menuBtn.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser , check this out

Comment: @FikriF i'm very new to javascript i don't have enough knowledge to understand your suggestion answer. It is now my problem because i only learn C programming language from my school, now I am struggling to understand basic syntax of different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matchMedia()` for javascript to keep track of the width of the screen. If the screen width meets the specified conditions, then the specified function is disabled by returning a **false**. Like that:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    function nameFunction() {
        return false;
    }
} else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect using this function.

```
function isMobile(){
    return window.innerWidth <= 600;
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you can detect Mobile device with below function.

```
function isMobile(){
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
   (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.platform))) {
    return true;
}
    return false;
}
```